# Main container is not showing scrollbar

Tags: css

Hello All I hope you are doing Fine! So actually I'm working a chatroom and Im having problem displaying the messages. You see what is actually happening is that when i enter a message the message box goes down. Instead what I want is that I want the messages at the top go behind the navbar and I want the container which shows the message to show a scrollbar so the message send box will stay in place
my index.php

```css
body {
  overflow: none;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.darker {
  border-color: #ccc;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.container img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container img.right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.time-right {
  float: right;
  color: #aaa;
}

.time-left {
  float: left;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <p>
    <div id="load_msg"></div>
  </p>
  <span class="time-right">11:00</span>
</div>

<div class="container darker">


  <form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message_id" />
    <button type="button" id="send_msg">Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, you should not have block-level elements like `<div>` inside `<p>` tags

Comment: hmmm Tried not working

Comment: It wasn't a solution, just general advice

Answer (score 1):

You have two `.container`: One for the messages and another for the form. You need to separate the two, so give the container for the messages an id. TheN you set a height for the container with the id.

HTML

```
<div class="container" id="msg">...</div>
<div class="container">...</div>
```

CSS

```
#msg {
  height: 100px;
}
```

Take a look at this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/luenib/mpLtbkon/)